# How often are parity checks actually required? (How often do such errors occur?)

Tags: parity

I'm aware of various systems put in place to carry out error checks so that corrupted data can be restored or at least identified, however how ***often do such corruptions take place***? Is it common for a parity check to be needed or just a precautionary measure?

Comment: Your question is way too broad.  There are books on this topic.

Comment: In what way is it too broad? "How often during normal use of a computer do bits get flipped from a 1 to a 0 or vice versa?"